# How add "href attribute" after "</a>"

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I want to show the value of "href" attribute at end-tag `</a>` for each anchor tag.

Instead, this code works only for the first link on the page.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').after($('a').attr('href'));
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You need to perform an each.  You are doing two global lookups.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function in a different way:

[.after( function-html )](http://api.jquery.com/after/#after-function-html)

> Type: Function( Integer index, String html ) => htmlString or Element or Text or jQuery
>   A function that returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), text node(s), or jQuery object to insert after each element in the set of matched elements. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old HTML value of the element as arguments. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the set.

In this way for each anchor you can return to the after method the correct text to print:

```js
$('a').after(function(idx, txt) {
    return this.getAttribute('href');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="url1">link text</a>
<a href="url2">link text</a>
<a href="url3">link text</a>
<a href="url4">link text</a>
```

Comment: Small nitpick.  If you're not going to use the `idx` or `txt`, why define them? :)

Comment: You are right, but I assume it's important in this case a full function description. A reduced format with ES6, for instance, would be more hard to read.

Comment: I'm not advocating the use of an arrow function, just not defining unused parameters.  But to explain the usage of a method, it could make sense.